# magento base image doesn't appear

Tags: php, image, magento

I want to load the product base image (main image) in a custom template.
When I use `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')`, it works perfectly.
But the base image shows the placeholder instead.

Can someone help me?

Comment: How do you get the `$_product` variable? From a collection? If so, please post the code that retrieves the collection to your question.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hojzc04mhhy1k9v/Screenshot%202014-01-14%2009.50.53.png

Comment: That doesn't help much. The important code is in `getLoadedProductCollection`.

Comment: I did copy that code from catalog/product/list template

Comment: Damn. Then it should work. All I can think of is to check if the small image is set in the backend at store view level. I have on other idea.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zik6fb1qsgxvro7/Screenshot%202014-01-14%2010.08.16.png 

I am trying to get the 'base image', the small image works fine (it is a configurable product)

Comment: I finally understood your problem. See my answer. If it's different that your solution then post your solution as an answer for people with the same issue and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The base image cannot be shown in the product list because it is not loaded in the list.
For any other attribute this would be an easy task, just edit the attribute in the backend and set the flag 'Used in product listing' to Yes.
But, unfortunately, for some reason still unknown to me, you cannot do that for image attributes.
You have to do it manually in the db. (yes I've said it...modify the db manually against all rules that say not to).
First you need to identify the base image attribute.

```
select * 
from 
    eav_attribute 
where 
    attribute_code = 'image' and 
    entity_type_id IN 
        (select 
              entity_type_id 
         from 
              eav_entity_type 
         where 
              entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
        )
```

This should get you one row. Take the id column from the result (for me is `85`) and run the following query that will set the attribute as used in product listing.

```
update 
    catalog_eav_attribute 
set 
    used_in_product_listing = 1
where
    attribute_id = 85
```

Replace `85` with the value you get from the first select then rebuild your indexes from `System->Index Management`.
Now you should be able to call the following code with success.

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It can also be done in an installer script using Magento models which would remove the "danger" for people scared of putting SQL into their code/work.

Comment: @RobbieAverill. yes, it can be done in an installer script. I just offered a quick and dirty solution here. From experience, more people are terrified of install scripts than they are of raw sql queries :)

Comment: Haha fair enough. Nice answer anyway, helped me